# Using an unconditional "IF" in a command line [BATCH]

Tags: batch-file, command, conditional-statements

My command line uses an "IF" in it.

apktool if SystemUI.apk

However, it wants to process this line as a condition statement and errors out.  How do I execute this command when I do not want the "IF" to be a condition but an actual part of the command??

Comment: can you paste your code into your question? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24391132/edit

Comment: I suggest to change the title of this topic by another one with more sense (_unconditional "IF"_???)